# Cannot run globally installed node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I cannot get my Mac OS 10.8.5 to find the modules that `npm` installed globally. I am trying to execute `bbb` from the command line, but when I try to execute it, I get

```
   $ bbb
    -bash: bbb: command not found
```

I believe it is installed correctly:

```
  $ npm ls -g | grep bbb
    ├── bbb@1.0.0-wip
    ├─┬ generator-bbb@0.3.1
    ├─┬ grunt-bbb-requirejs@0.1.0-alpha.6
    ├─┬ grunt-bbb-server@0.1.0-alpha.13
    ├─┬ grunt-bbb-styles@0.1.0-alpha.5
```

Lots of people recommended putting `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` in their `$PATH` so I tried that:

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Does anyone have any other ideas with what can be going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in [bbb](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb)'s `package.json`, it has no `bin` property, so you can't execute the command from the command line because it was not written to have command line functionality. Not all Node.js modules are created with use on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

the `bin` of the location where your npm is installing the global packages needs to be in your path.

For example when i install a global package i get:

`npm install -g npm-check-updates
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/bin/ncu -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates/bin/ncu
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/bin/npm-check-updates -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates/bin/npm-check-updates`

You can see in the output above that directory where my executable files are is: `/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/bin`. So in my case I have added that location to my path.

Check your `bin` location and add that.